# create a desktop shortcut icon for studio.sh

Tags: android-studio

I recently have downloaded android studio to develop android.
I run program at terminal typing ./studio.sh
My question is :
Is there any way to start it as a GUI icon at desktop without use terminal.

Comment: Inside Android Studio:

    Android Studio -> Tools -> Create Desktop Entry

Answer (score 38, accepted):

To create a desktop file do this:

1. Open Gedit.
2. Paste the following into the file, editing the relevant parts:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
   [Desktop Entry]
   Version=1.0
   Type=Application
   Terminal=false
   Icon=someicon
   Exec=sh /path/to/studio.sh
   Name=Android Studio
   ```
3. Now, save this file as **somename.desktop**, to your desktop.
4. Next, you need to make this file executable by typing the command:

   ```
   cd ~/Desktop && chmod a+x somename.desktop
   ```

Now, double-clicking the application should launch your application.

Comment: Glad! I could help.

Comment: for help other.enter Icon such: /home/ur_pc_name/path/to/icon.ico

Comment: android studio icon as `studio.png` is also located at the same place where you have your `studio.sh`

Comment: When you start android studio, there is an option named `configure`. In the `configure` option, you will get `Create a desktop Entry for Studio`. Just do a couple of okays, and after restarting you can find Android Studio in your system menu. Checked in Ubuntu 16.04..:)

Comment: Android Studio -> Tools -> Create Desktop Entry

Comment: @IhabShoully doesn't work for Linux Deepin 15.11

Comment: As of the latest version of Android Studio, which is typically installed in `/usr/local/android-studio`, you can launch `/usr/local/android-studio/bin/studio.sh`, go to Configure -> Create Desktop Entry. Requires password if creating for all users. This is just an updated version of @IhabShoully's comment.

Comment: In 2022 with dolphin, when you start studio.sh, you get a "welcome" screen with 3 big buttons pertaining to projects, and a side column with "Projects", "Customize", "Plugins", and "Learn Andriod Studio". So I don't see where "Configure" is. Under "Customize" there is a dialog with "Color Theme", "Accessibility", and "Keymap". Continuing from here is just a confusing exercise of which thing is like "Configure / Create Desktop Entry" without being called that exactly?