# How to change icon in the scroll bar?

Tags: icons, scrollbar

I have a shortcut in the scroll bar:

[image]

As you can see, the icon is a question mark (marked in black circle). This icon represents a shortcut to a software I use. I want to change the image to an svg file I already have.

Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create a desktop shortcut icon for studio.sh](http://askubuntu.com/questions/713401/create-a-desktop-shortcut-icon-for-studio-sh)

Comment: You need to create a `.desktop` file for it and its easy to do so.

Comment: Look for the `*.desktop` launcher of the program you are running.  Edit that file, placing a pathname to the **Icon=** entry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I edit/create new launcher items in Unity by hand?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand)